# The maximum between two real numbers at denominator

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, maxima-minima, fractions

In writing a proof I have encountered a problem that I hope to solve here.
If I have in general a term like
$$\frac{1}{\max\{a,b\}}$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ then it is right to say the following?
$$\frac{1}{\max\{a,b\}}\leq \min\left \{\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b}\right \}$$

Comment: It's true with equality when both $a$ and $b$ are positive. Work out the other cases by example.

Comment: Oh yes, I agree! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There will be three cases possible:

1. a and b both are positive.
   Without any loss of generality, we can assume a to be smaller than b. Then, in that case, max{a,b} = $\frac{1}{b}$ and $min\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}\}$ = 1/b. Therefore, $\frac{1}{max\{a,b\}}$ = $min\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}\}$. Equality holds.
2. among a and b, one is positive and other is negative.
   Again, without any loss of generality, we can assume a is negative. Then, in that case, max{a,b} = b and $min\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}\}$ = $\frac{1}{a}$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{max\{a,b\}}$ > $min\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}\}$, as a is negative. Hence the give equality fails.
3. a and b both are negative.
   Without any loss of generality, we can assume a to be smaller than b. Then, in that case, max{a,b} = b and $min\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}\}$ = $\frac{1}{b}$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{max\{a,b\}}$ = $min\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}\}$, as both are negative. Equality holds.

Hence, the given equality holds only when both the numbers are either positive or negative.

Comment: In the case of $a$ and $b$ are both negative we have equality, check your calculations.
Also, you used $x$ and $y$ instead of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @jjagmath Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: You corrected the use of $x$ and $y$ instead of $a$ and $b$, but the case of $a$ and $b$ both negative is still wrong.

Comment: @jjagmath I guess it is correct. You can check it by taking a = -3 and b = -2.

Comment: If $a=-3$ and $b=-2$ then $\min\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}\} = \min\{-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{2}\} = -\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{b}$ but you wrote $\frac{1}{a}$. It's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is false. Take, for example, $a=1$ and $b=-1$.

Then $$\frac{1}{\max\{a, b\}} = \frac{1}{\max\{1, -1\}} = \frac{1}{1}=1$$
and $$\min\left\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}\right\} = \min\left\{\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{-1}\right\} = \min \{1,-1\} = -1$$